# Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence wit limit $L$. With out using the Heine-Borel theorem, prove that the set $\{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$ is compact.

Tags: calculus, general-topology

Let $a_n$ be a convergent sequence wit limit $L$. With out using the Heine-Borel theorem, prove that the set $\{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$ is compact.

I know that $a_n$ is convergent to $L$, meaning for all $\epsilon >0$, there exists an $N>0$ such that

$n>N$   implies $|a_n -L|< \epsilon $

I also know that $a_n$ is convergent, so it's bounded, so is $\{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$ . I can prove this set is both bounded and closed, so it's sequentially compact, hence compact. But I'm not allowed to use this theorem. How can I use the above info to prove that set is compact?

Comment: Given an open cover, one of its elements, $O$, contains $L$. But $O$ then contains all but finitely many elements of your set.

Comment: the fact you mention Heine borel means we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$ or you want a general proof for a general metric space? (in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is very simple to show this result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set $A$ is compact in a space $X$ if given any arbitrary collection of open sets $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup G_{\lambda}$ then there is a *finite* collection of sets from $\{G_{\lambda}\}$, say $\{G_1, G_2, ..., G_n\}$ such that $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i = 1}^n G_i$. What this essentially means is if there is say a infinite collection of open sets which contain $A$ then there are a finite number of sets from the said collection which also contain $A$. Example, Say $x \not \in A$. Then the collection of sets $\{B_n \ | \ n \in \Bbb N\}$ where $B_n = \{y \ | \ || y - x|| \lt n\}$ where contains $A$. If $A$ is compact there are finite number of sets $B_{m_1}, B_{m_2}, \cdots B_{m_n}$ such that $A$ is contained in the union $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n B_{m_i} $. This is the primary definition of compactness. The "bounded and closed" definition is the Heine-Borel Theorem. [Read more here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160578/understanding-the-definition-of-a-compact-set) A collection of sets of the form $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ is called an open cover of $A$. The reason we use the subscript $ \lambda$ here is to emphasise that the collection $\{G_{\lambda}\} $ can be infinite and uncountable in fact.

Now to prove that a set $A$ is compact we must prove every open cover of $A$ contains a finite subcover. The terminology here should be clear due to the above example. So we must assume an arbitrary open cover of $A$ and prove there are a finite number of sets from that collection (the open cover) which also contain $A$. Let us get to it.

Let $A = \{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$. Assume there is an open cover $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ - as explained above -  such that $A \subseteq \bigcup G_{\lambda}$. Since $L \in A$ there is a set $G_{\alpha} \in \{G_{\lambda}\}$ such that $L \in G_{\alpha}$. Now by definition $G_{\alpha}$ is an open set. By definition a set $Q$ is open if for each $x \in Q$ there is $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $ \{y \ | \ |y - x| \lt \epsilon \} \subseteq Q $. This follows from the fact that every open set (in $\Bbb R$ if you will) contains a neighbourhood of each of its points, by definition. So since $L \in G_{\alpha} $there is an $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that $  \{y \ | \ |y - L| \lt \epsilon \} \subseteq  G_{\alpha}$. Now since $L$ is the limit of the sequence $(a_n)$ given  any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there is an $m \in \Bbb N$ such that $ n \ge m \implies | a_m - L | \lt \epsilon$. Therefore we can infer that all elements in $(a_n)$ whose index is larger than $m$ are in $ \{y \ | \ |y - L| \lt \epsilon \} $. Therefore we get that

$$ \{L, a_m, a_{m + 1}, a_{m + 2}, a_{m + 3}, \cdots\} \subseteq \{y \ | \ |y - L| \lt \epsilon \} \subseteq  G_{\alpha} ----- (1) $$

Now we are almost done. We have shown that every element $a_n$ for $n \ge m$ is contained in exactly one specific set - the one which also contains $L$ - from the collection $\{G_{\lambda}\}$. Now all we need is to prove that the rest of the elements in $A$ are also contained in a finite number of sets in the collection $\{G_{\lambda}\} $. This is easy since $a_i \in A \implies a_i \in \bigcup G_{\lambda} \implies a_i \in G_i $ where $G_i \in \{G_{\lambda}\}$ is some set in the collection. And this is true for each $i = 1 ... m - 1$. So by $(1)$ the collection $\{ G_{\alpha}, G_1, G_2, ...G_{m - 1} \}$ forms a ***finite*** sub-collection of sets from $\{G_{\lambda}\}$ whose union contains $A$.

$\{G_{\lambda}\}$ here was chosen arbitrarily so this is true for any open cover of $A$ and hence by definition $A$ is compact.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 9):

Given the set $\{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$ take a covering by open sets  $\{U_i, i \in I\}$.

One of the $U$ namely $U_{i_L}$ contains the point $L$. Being $L$ a point of $U_{i_L}$, because $U_{i_L}$ is open exists $r>0$ which $B(L,r) \subset U_{i_L}$.

In the convergence definition for $a_n$ take $\epsilon=r$, then exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ which $ \forall n\geq N$ implies $|a_n-L|<r$. That means every point of the succesion for $n\geq N$ is contained in the ball (because the distance to the center $L$ is less than $r$), i.e.: $$a_n \in B(L,r), \forall n \geq N$$
and therefore in the set $U_{i_L}$.

Each point in the succesion with $n<N$ is contained in at least one of the $\{U_i, i \in I\}$, for each one of they pick one $U_{i_n} \in \{U_i, i \in I\}$ with the property $a_n \in U_{i_n}$. Then $a_1,...a_{N-1}$ is covered by $\{U_{i_1},U_{i_2},...,U_{i_{N-1}}\}$.

Finally the covering $\{U_{i_1},U_{i_2},...,U_{i_{N-1}},U_L\}$ is a finite covering of the set $\{L,a_1,a_2,...\}$ because the last one covers the succesion for $n\geq N$ (and the limit point $L$) and the first ones covers the beginning of the succesion.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion: For each $ε>0$ there is $N \in \mathbb N$ so that $$a_n \in B_ε(L)$$ for all $n\ge N$. In words, there are only finite many $a_k$ that are not in this open ball around $L$. Now take the open cover $$\mathcal O=\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^{N-1}B_{δ_k}(a_k)\right)\cup B_ε(L)$$ which contains $\{L,a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$, in symbols $$\{L,a_1,a_2,\ldots\} \subset \mathcal O$$This is finite and minimal in the sense that you can choose the constants $δ_k$ and $ε$ arbitrarily small. So every open cover $\mathcal U$ of $\{L,a_1,a_2,\ldots\}$ contains the finite subcover $\mathcal O$.

(Although, this last sentence "So..." can require a better justification. But if $\mathcal U$ is a random open cover then there are open balls around each $a_n$ and $L$ that contain them. So this balls contain the balls defined in $\mathcal O$ and the conclusion follows).

Otherwise, if you were allowed to use that compact means closed and bounded, you could note that every subsequence $\left(a_{n_j}\right)_{j\in J}$ of the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ converges also to $L$ (subsequence of convergent sequence), which makes $L$ the single limit point of the given set.

Comment: May I have a question please? from your argument, what does $X$ refer to? $\{L,a_1,a_2...\}$? Usually, I understand $X= \mathbb R^n$ and $C$ mean the compact set. I just want to verify if you use it the same way.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Yes, sorry for the unclear notation. $X=\{L, a_1, a_2, \ldots\}$ indeed as you say. I also denote usually with $C$ the compact set, but here I used a caligraphic C. I used caligraphic letters $\mathcal{O}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ to denote the open covers. I changed C to U.. Is it better now?

Comment: I tried your way, and my professor told me that I can't just pick the open cover. I have to assume that it's arbitrary, then prove that every single one of those contain finitely many subcovering.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif It is arbitrary. The idea is that there is a set that contains L and infinitely many of the $a_n$. But since your professor said otherwise I cannot convince you... (Pick the answer below, which says the same, but has +3)

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif P.s. sorry to let you down.

Comment: no, it's not your fault, my professor is crazy sometime. This concept is very important, but she let a student lecture it, which cause confusion to the whole class. I understand your explanation way better than that guy in my class. I just have problem to put it in word to give a solid argument.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif What you should say, is that any open covering will have an open set that contains $L$. But around $L$ (that is in $ε$ distance for every $ε>0$ are infinitely many $a_n$. So now there remain finitely many $a_n$ which can be covered by finitely many open sets (since we have assumed that we already have the cover, albeit infinite). However, pick the answer below... it's safe :)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover of the set $\{L,a_1,a_2,\dots\}$. There exists some index $i\in I$ such that $U_i$ contains $L$. The fact that $a_n\to L$ implies that $U_i$ will contain *all but finitely many of the $a_n$*, or in other words, $U_i$ will contain $a_n$ for $n\geq M$ for some $M\in \mathbb N$. That's by the definition of convegence in topological spaces ( see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence).

Now, take the sets $U_{j_n}$ that contain some $a_n$ for $n=1,\dots,M-1$, and you have covered everything using
$$U_i \cup \bigcup_{n=1}^{M-1}U_{j_n}$$