# Is the following space compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is the subspace of rational numbers in the usual space of real numbers compact?

I'm not exactly sure what this is asking. Is this asking if I can generate a cover using a finite amount of sets from the rational numbers to cover all of the real numbers? Apparently, the answer is yes, but I'm not sure I could find a way to cover the irrational numbers.

Comment: When you say you're not sure what is being asked, do you mean you don't understand what the space of rational numbers is, or that you don't understand what it means for a space to be compact?

Comment: $\Bbb Q$ is neither closed since $\overline{\Bbb Q}=\Bbb R\ne \Bbb Q$ nor bounded since the sequence $(n)$ is in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @MJD I know what it means for a space to be compact, and I think I know what the space of rational numbers is. It's simply the rational numbers where the open sets are non-singleton sets of rational numbers, right? I'm a bit confused how to piece this all together

Comment: No, the open sets are open intervals.  You have given the rationals the discrete topology, which is not the usual one.  Note that "open sets are non-singletons" implies that singletons are *also* open sets, because if $\{a, b\}$ is open and $\{a, c\}$ is open, then so is their intersection $\{a \}$.

Comment: It sounds like your confusion is about what the "usual" topology is on the set of rational numbers.  This is the subspace topology inherited from the reals; the open sets in $\mathbb{Q}$ are precisely sets $O \cap \mathbb{Q}$, where $O$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: Wait, but if the open sets are open intervals, then doesn't that include irrationals? Edit: Nevermind, I see it in an answer below

Comment: They are open intervals of rationals.  An open interval of reals is a set of reals $\{ x\in \Bbb R \mid a < x< b\}$ for some reals $a$ and $b$.  An open interval of rationals is similarly a set of *rationals* $\{ x\in \color{green}{\Bbb Q} \mid a < x< b\}$.  Or put another way, it is a set $O\cap \Bbb Q$ where $O$ is an open set of reals.

Answer (score 1):

Consider just the set $\Bbb Q$ of rational numbers, with the usual topology, which is that open sets are intervals of the form $$(a,b) = \{ x\in \Bbb Q \mid a < x < b \}$$ and unions of those intervals.

The question is:

> In this topology, is the entire space $\Bbb Q$ compact?

That is, if someone gives you a family $\mathcal F$ of open intervals whose union is all of $\Bbb Q$, can you guarantee to find a **finite** subfamily of $\mathcal F$ whose union is also all of $\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Well, wouldn't two open intervals be $(-\infty, 1), (-1, \infty)$? If you take the union, you get $\mathbb{Q}$, and it only took two.

Comment: @david Yes, but that is not the question.  The question is that if *I* pick some family of open intervals that covers $\Bbb Q$, can *you* guarantee that you will be able to find a finite subfamily that also covers $\Bbb Q$.  Obviously if I give you a finite family in the first place, you can hand it back to me unchanged.  But what if I hand you some large infinite family of intervals?

Comment: @david Maybe read this answer in [Understanding the definition of a compact set](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/160604/25554) where I explained it in more detail.

Comment: If you hand me a large infinite family of intervals, could I take the union of some of these and claim that to be one interval? Is this not allowed?

Comment: Because if you have a large infinite family of intervals that cover $\mathbb{Q}$, then surely you have a large infinite family of intervals that cover any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$. If I take the union of enough of these to make two subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ that overlap, like in my comment above, I win?

Comment: If you do that, it has nothing to do with compactness.   Consider the family $\def\F{\mathcal F}\F = \{ (0,2), (1,3), (5,7)\}$.  This family has three elements.  The interval $(0,3)$ is not an element of $\F$, and it is not an element of any subfamily of $\F$.  Subfamilies of $\F$ contain only the intervals $(0,2), (1,3)$, or $(5,7)$.  The family $\{(0,2), (5,7)\}$ is a subfamily of $\F$, as is $\{(0,2), (1,3)\}$. When I give you a family of intervals, you get to pick out some of them to make your subfamily, but you are not allowed to change them.

Comment: Then, I don't think there is a way to choose them in such a way that the rationals are compact. I can't be assured that in the infinite set, I have a finite amount that create any of the subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$ to use.

Comment: The rationals are either compact or not; it doesn't depend on how you choose the set of intervals.  The rationals are compact if, for *every* chosen family of intervals that covers $\Bbb Q$, there is always a way to choose a finite subfamily that covers $\Bbb Q$. You need to decide whether $\Bbb Q$ is compact, and then that determines which side of the game you play.

Comment: Unless, I state something of the nature of 'in a family of infinite sets that covers $\mathbb{Q}$, there must be a finite subcover that covers a subset, namely $(-\infty, 0)$ and a finite subcover that covers $(0, \infty)$. If we take these together, they cover $\mathbb{Q}$ finitely.

Comment: But, I don't think I can just state that. My hunch is the rationals aren't compact because I don't have the guarantee of 'finite'.

Comment: If you would like to discuss this in chat, [click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/13771/compactness?tab=general)

Answer (score 0):

A subspace $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact, means that for *every* family of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that covers $A$, we can find a *finite* subfamily that also covers $A$.

In $\mathbb{R}$ we know that $A$ compact implies that $A$ is bounded: we can take the family $(-n,n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$; these have the whole of the reals as their union, so every $A$ is covered by it. A finite subfamily is covering the same as one of them (for the largest $n$), and so $A \subset (-n,n)$ for some $n$.

This doesn't happen for the rationals...