# Let $K \subset \mathbb{R^1}$ consist of $0$ and the numbers $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$. Prove that $K$ is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

> Let $K \subset \mathbb{R^1}$ consist of $0$ and the number $\frac{1}{n}$ for $n = 1,2,3,...$. Prove that $K$ is compact.

---

**My (Attempted) Proof**

$K = \left\{0, \left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\right\}$.

Put $E =\left\{E_n\right\} = \left\{(n-1, n+1)\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$. Note that the $(n-1, n+1)$ represents an interval in $\mathbb{R^1}$, and not a 2-tuple/ordered-pair.

It is clear that $E \subset \mathbb{R^1}$, and since $E$ is a collection of open sets, $E$ is also open.

Now $K \subset E$, and thus $E$ is an open cover of $K$. If we take $E_0 \in \left\{E_n\right\}$, we can see that $K \subset E_0$, and since $\{E_0\}$ is a finite collection and a subset of $E$, $K$ must be compact. $\square$

---

Is my proof logically sound and rigorously correct? Furthermore is my proof an example of what is generally called a *constructive proof*?

Comment: When showing compactness, we don't get to *choose* an open cover---we must proceed to show that *any* possible open cover reduces to a finite cover.

Comment: @erfink. What happens then, if some open covers reduce to a finite cover, while others don't (if that is even possible)? Wouldn't showing the existence of a single open cover reducing to a finite cover show that the subset of that finite cover is compact? I'm just trying to understand why we need to show the reduction from an open cover to a finite cover for all open covers, instead of just for one.

Comment: @Perturbative - You seem to be confused about the notion of compactness. The definition is that **every** open cover reduces to some **finite** subcover. You may think of it like this: no matter how many open blankets you throw on the space, we will find that only a finite number of them were needed.

Comment: Relevant and possibly helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/160578/understanding-the-definition-of-a-compact-set/160604#160604

Comment: No.  You have shown *an* open cover has a finite subcover.  That is not enough.  You must show *every* open cover has a finite subcover.  You must show if *any* open set contains 0, then it contains an infinite number of 1/n and indeed there are only a finite number of 1/n not contained.  You need to show this is true for *all* open sets containing 0.

Comment: When you declare E ={$E_{\alpha} $} is an open cover, you can *not* then define what $E_i $ is in any way (not even that it is countable), because it *has* to represent *all* possible covers.  But you can say $0\in F$ for some open set in the cover.   We can rename F as $E_0$.  As $E_0$ is open there is an $e>0$ so that (-e,e) $\subset E_0$ and for all $n > 1/e $, $1/n \in (-e,e) $.  The has *nothing* to do with what E_0 actually is.  For each $n \le 1/e $ we know some open G in the cover contains 1/n.  If we name it $E_n $ we have a finite subcover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, this is wrong. It's not enough to find a finite open cover of $K$. (*Every* set, whether compact or not, has a finite open cover.). This is a very common mistake when people first learn about compactness.

Instead, you must show that if you are given an open cover of $K$, say $C$, then you can find a finite subset of $C$ that is also a cover of $K$.

Your proof should begin "Let $C$ be an open cover of $K$." (That is, $C$ is a family of open sets whose union contains $K$). Then show how, no matter what is in $C$, you can find a finite subset of $C$ that is also a cover of $K$

Hint: There must be some element of $C$ that includes 0. (Why?). Call this element $g$. Then $g$ must be an open set. (Why?) What else must $g$ cover?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Here's a quick proof.

Let $\{U_\alpha\}$ be an open cover of $K$. In particular, there exists an open set say $U_1$ such that $0 \in U_1$. Since $0$ is a limit point of $K$, then $U_1$ contains all but finitely many $1/n$. Now I will let the reader finish the prove.